# AppCheck not protecting resource as expected

Tags: android, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I implemented AppCheck to protect a backend endpoint but it doesn't work as intended.

So far the basics work, as I followed the instructions for [NodeJs (backend)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend#node.js) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/custom-resource) (with the PlayIntegrity provider). I also configured everything in Firebase and Google Cloud console. My API endpoint is "protected", as I can't access it without an appCheckToken.

The problem is, that I uploaded my app to the Google Play console and released it as an internal test. In the Play console settings for PlayIntegrity I configured, that it should require `MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY`. When I install the test build on a device that only passes `MEETS_BASIC_INTEGRITY` (tested with Simple Play Integrity Checker app), it can still access the protected resource.

Are there any additional settings I need to take care of?

How can I make sure, that only devices that pass `MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY` can access my resource?